# How to get octants in matplotlib 3D?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
```

After plotting some points,  when I use the plt.show() method then it displays a 3D axes system but there is only one octant. I need all 8 of them for my project. Is there any way to get them? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Plot something in the other octants or manually set the x y and z limits

Comment: You're saying that if I plot 2 points A(1, 2, 3) and B(-1, 2, 3) then the plot will automatically show 2 octants as point A and B lie in two different octants?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should put your data (presumably negative) in view when you plot it.  However, it's worth knowing how to manually set the limits as well:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.set_xlim(-1,1)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
ax.set_zlim(-1,1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I shall implement it and get back to you.